# meaning of the phrase "by actual count"?

Tags: meaning, articles

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/0bNdhM4vt4I). It is at around 8 minute and 34 second. Here is the context:

> The paper even cites a case from the 1691 where a pregnant woman consumed, by actual count, 1,400 salted herrings during her pregnancy.

I feel it means it was actually counted, if I am right, then why did the host omit the article *a* before the phrase *actual count*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase **by actual count** there is not referring to an instance of counting but to a *mode* of counting, enumeration versus estimation or extrapolation.

When referring to the mode of something, an article is not used.

Compare:

> They went by train.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get it. Could you please rephrase the answer?

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope:   What don't you get? Do you know what **mode** means? As in "mode of transport"?

Comment: If it was said that the woman ate 500 kilos of fish, then could I say the woman ate, by mass, 500 kilos of fish?

Comment: We can say *This carton is packaged **by weight** not **by volume***.  You could say "by actual weight" to distinguish the mode of measurement from estimates or using average weight of a fish, etc.